# 3dmin parse is unable to start activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse, min3d

I am very new on java/android, just worked with processing before. Therefore all those packages, sources, libs are really a problem for me. 
Right now I would like to load an .obj file using the min3d library. The problem is, that i want to display the .obj on the  [commmander 3d tablet](http://commander3d.com/). Therefore I downloaded an working example for the tablet with a stereoscopic 3d renderer class from this [SDK no need to log in](http://www.sdeck.org). In the package, where in my example cubes are generated, i would like to instead load the .obj. But I get an activity error. I am not sure, if the .obj is found, but i think it should, because if i only load it and do not parse it, i don't get an error. But if I start to parse: "parser.parse();" then the mess begins. The .obj is in this folders: SampleActivity > res > raw > camaro_obj. The next 3 lines aftzer the parse i already uncommented, because at first this should work. But i know already, that the appChild is not avaible. This will be the next problem. Below is the code of the package, the console and the logCat. THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!! best Markus!

```
   /*
 * Copyright (c) 2014. Sun Game Corp. All rights reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 * software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 * "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND,
 * either express or implied. See the License for the specific
 * language governing permissions and limitations under the License.
 */

package com.sungame.sdeck.sample.render;

import android.content.Context;
import android.opengl.Matrix;
import android.view.*;
import com.sungame.sdeck.sample.R;
import com.sungame.sdeck.sample.model.Scene;
import com.sungame.sdeck.sample.shader.ShaderProgram;
import com.sungame.sdeck.sample.shader.TextureProgram;

//import min3d.sampleProject1.IParser;

import org.sdeck.SDeConfig;
import org.sdeck.SDecKit;
import org.sdeck.renderer.AbstractRenderer;

import static android.opengl.GLES20.*;

import min3d.core.Object3dContainer;
import min3d.core.RendererActivity;
import min3d.parser.IParser;
import min3d.parser.Parser;
import min3d.vos.Light;

/**
 * Render a stereo scene.
 */
public class StereoRenderer extends AbstractRenderer implements View.OnTouchListener {

private final Scene scene;
private ShaderProgram program;
private float mDepthZ = -10.0f;

private float mPrevX;
private float mPrevY;

protected final float[] mvpMatrix      = newMatrix();  // "Model View Projection Matrix"
protected final float[] projMatrix     = newMatrix();  // Projection matrix
protected final float[] viewMatrix     = newMatrix();  // View matrix

private static final float EYE_Z = -1f;
private static final float NEAR_Z = 3.0f;
private static final float FAR_Z = 30.0f;
private static final float MAX_DEPTH_Z = -(NEAR_Z + 2.0f);
private static final float MIN_DEPTH_Z = -(FAR_Z - 7.0f);
private static final float SCREEN_PLANE_Z = 10.0f;
private static final float FOV = 45.0f;
private static final float IOD = 0.2f;

private Object3dContainer objModel;

public StereoRenderer (Context context, Scene scene) {
    super( createKit(context) );
    this.scene = scene;
    IParser parser = Parser.createParser(Parser.Type.OBJ,context.getResources(), "com.sungame.sdeck.sample:raw/camaro_obj", true);
    parser.parse();

    //objModel = parser.getParsedObject();
    //objModel.scale().x = objModel.scale().y = objModel.scale().z = .7f;
    //scene.addChild(objModel);
}

private static SDecKit createKit (Context context) {
    SDeConfig config = new SDeConfig.Builder( context.getApplicationContext() )
                            .setNearZ( NEAR_Z )
                            .setFarZ( FAR_Z )
                            .setScreenZ( SCREEN_PLANE_Z )
                            .setFOV( FOV ) 
                            .setIOD( IOD )
                            .create();
    return new SDecKit( config );
}

@Override
protected float[] onSetupProjection () {
    return projMatrix;
}

private void setupGL () {
    glClearColor( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
    glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
    glEnable ( GL_CULL_FACE  );
    glEnable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );
    glDisable( GL_DITHER );
}

@Override
protected void onSurfaceCreated () {
    setupGL();
    program = new TextureProgram( R.raw.texture_vertex, R.raw.texture_shader );
    program.useProgram();
}

@Override
protected void onSurfaceChanged (int w, int h) {
    scene.setup( w, h );
}

/**
 * Draw the full scene.
 */
protected void onDrawFrame () {
    // Draw background color
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

    super.onDrawFrame();  // let super handler the rest.

    scene.drawEnd();
}

@Override
protected void onDrawScene (float[] projMatrix) {
    // Set the camera position (View matrix)
    //setLookAtM( viewMatrix, 0, 0f, 0f, EYE_Z, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1f, 0f );
    Matrix.setIdentityM( viewMatrix, 0 );

    // Calculate the projection and view transformation
    Matrix.multiplyMM( mvpMatrix, 0, projMatrix, 0, viewMatrix, 0 );
    Matrix.translateM( mvpMatrix, 0, 0, 0, mDepthZ );

    // Draw
    scene.draw( mvpMatrix, program );
}

public void moveCam (float deltaX) {
    deltaX /= (float)width;
    deltaX *= 20.0f;
    mDepthZ += deltaX;
    if (mDepthZ >= MAX_DEPTH_Z)
        mDepthZ = MAX_DEPTH_Z;
    else if (mDepthZ <= MIN_DEPTH_Z)
        mDepthZ = MIN_DEPTH_Z;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent e) {
    if (e.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        mPrevX = e.getX();
        mPrevY = e.getY();
    }
    if (e.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        float deltaX = e.getX() - mPrevX;
        float deltaY = e.getY() - mPrevY;
        moveCam( deltaX );
        scene.onTouch( deltaX, deltaY );
        mPrevX = e.getX();
        mPrevY = e.getY();
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

```
> Android Launch!
[2014-11-17 15:10:10 - SampleActivity] adb is running normally.
[2014-11-17 15:10:10 - SampleActivity] Performing com.sungame.sdeck.sample.SampleActivity activity launch
[2014-11-17 15:10:11 - SampleActivity] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2014-11-17 15:10:11 - SampleActivity] Starting activity com.sungame.sdeck.sample.SampleActivity on device 0146D5EF0801D014
[2014-11-17 15:10:11 - SampleActivity] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.sungame.sdeck.sample/.SampleActivity }

11-17 22:08:00.960: I/SDecKit(5151): S3D runtime environment available.
11-17 22:08:01.023: D/libEGL(5151): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
11-17 22:08:01.031: D/libEGL(5151): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX544_112.so
11-17 22:08:01.039: D/libEGL(5151): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX544_112.so
11-17 22:08:01.039: D/libEGL(5151): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX544_112.so
11-17 22:08:01.257: D/OpenGLRenderer(5151): Enabling debug mode 0
11-17 22:08:01.460: D/dalvikvm(5151): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 142K, 3% free 9096K/9347K, paused 10ms
11-17 22:08:01.460: I/dalvikvm-heap(5151): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.954MB for 1048592-byte allocation
11-17 22:08:01.484: D/dalvikvm(5151): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 4% free 10119K/10439K, paused 1ms+1ms
11-17 22:08:18.570: I/Process(5214): Sending signal. PID: 5214 SIG: 9
11-17 22:08:22.195: I/SDecKit(5253): S3D runtime environment available.
11-17 22:08:22.210: D/Min3D(5253): Start parsing object com.sungame.sdeck.sample:raw/camaro_obj
11-17 22:08:22.210: D/Min3D(5253): Start time 1416233302218
11-17 22:08:22.218: D/AndroidRuntime(5253): Shutting down VM
11-17 22:08:22.218: W/dalvikvm(5253): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40aa41f8)
11-17 22:08:22.218: E/AndroidRuntime(5253): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-17 22:08:22.218: E/AndroidRuntime(5253): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sungame.sdeck.sample/com.sungame.sdeck.sample.SampleActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-17 22:08:22.218: E/AndroidRuntime(5253):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
11-17 22:08:22.218: E/AndroidRuntime(5253):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
11-17 22:08:22.218: E/AndroidRuntime(5253):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
11-17 22:08:22.218: E/AndroidRuntime(5253):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
11-17 22:08:22.218: E/AndroidRuntime(5253):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-17 22:08:22.218: E/AndroidRuntime(5253):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-17 22:08:22.218: E/AndroidRuntime(5253):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
11-17 22:08:22.218: E/AndroidRuntime(5253):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-17 22:08:22.218: E/AndroidRuntime(5253):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-17 22:08:22.218: E/AndroidRuntime(5253):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
11-17 22:08:22.218: E/AndroidRuntime(5253):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
11-17 22:08:22.218: E/AndroidRuntime(5253):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-17 22:08:22.218: E/AndroidRuntime(5253): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-17 22:08:22.218: E/AndroidRuntime(5253):     at min3d.Utils.makeBitmapFromResourceId(Utils.java:26)
11-17 22:08:22.218: E/AndroidRuntime(5253):     at min3d.Utils.makeBitmapFromResourceId(Utils.java:47)
11-17 22:08:22.218: E/AndroidRuntime(5253):     at min3d.parser.ObjParser.readMaterialLib(ObjParser.java:213)
11-17 22:08:22.218: E/AndroidRuntime(5253):     at min3d.parser.ObjParser.parse(ObjParser.java:107)
11-17 22:08:22.218: E/AndroidRuntime(5253):     at com.sungame.sdeck.sample.render.StereoRenderer.<init>(StereoRenderer.java:72)
11-17 22:08:22.218: E/AndroidRuntime(5253):     at com.sungame.sdeck.sample.SampleActivity.onCreate(SampleActivity.java:52)
11-17 22:08:22.218: E/AndroidRuntime(5253):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
11-17 22:08:22.218: E/AndroidRuntime(5253):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
11-17 22:08:22.218: E/AndroidRuntime(5253):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
11-17 22:08:22.218: E/AndroidRuntime(5253):     ... 11 more
11-17 22:08:22.664: I/dalvikvm(5253): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
11-17 22:08:22.671: I/dalvikvm(5253): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
11-17 22:08:22.757: I/dalvikvm(5253): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
11-17 22:08:22.757: I/dalvikvm(5253): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Comment: what is at line 72 StereoRenderer.java:72

Comment: The StereoRenderer is a class based on AbstractRenderer. It is part of the Commander3D tablet sdk. Find it in the sdk docu on the left side: [link] (http://www.sdeck.org/documentation/) @MohammedAli Now I have exchanged 3dmin with Rajawali but i still get there error, that the activity cannot be started. Thank you very much!